# How can I install a light fixture when the junction box is partially blocked by a mirror?

Tags: electrical, lighting, drywall, bathroom-fixtures

I wanted to replace light fixture in my bathroom. When I removed the light fixture I noticed that electrical box was being slightly blocked by the wall mirror which is 10ft x 5ft. (see picture)

Now here's my dilemma. I cannot install a new light fixture as part of light fixture will sit over the mirror. If I try to screw it in then there will be space between the wall and light fixture. What can I do?

Cutting the mirror, moving the mirror down or moving the electrical box is not an option.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say you can't move the box. Why?

Comment: There is just so much I can do on my own and that is one thing that will require too much talent i.e. electrical, drilling, drywall repair of existing hole etc.All I wanted to do was remove existing light fixture and replace it with something else

Comment: Fair enough, but you have just one cable coming in, and it appears to be from above. It would be quite easy to move the box up a few inches and repair the drywall. You'd then have a much more professional-looking result.

Comment: Who would notice that the mirror is cut by 2 inches for $20?

Comment: Those things you say are not options?  Call the electrical inspector in. The moment he sees this setup, one of those things will *become* an option.  Because your current setup is a code violation.  Fixing this is mandatory, and those "not options" are your only choices that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

This one is a huge bummer. You don't have many options here.

Either cut out the box and replace it higher up, or re-mount it higher on the stud, or lower the mirror. Whether you can re-use the box depends on what kind of box it is and how it is mounted. I think moving the box is by far the easier option.

Comment: Yeah, I can't move that. Would somehow adding Deep Pan Box Extension Ring help?

Comment: If you cannot move the box then hire a professional electrician that can move it. There will be a huge advantage to raise the electrical box as well. This would significantly lower how much of the mirror is obscured by the lighting fixture.

Answer (score 3):

I would trace the outline of that oval-shaped piece of your light fixture onto a piece of wood about as thick as or very slightly thicker than your mirror.
Cut it out and then cut off a flat from the bottom so that it fits above your mirror over the junction box in the wall.
Drill mounting holes through it so that the fixture's mounting screws pass through.
Paint it either the same color as your wall, or see if you can find a metallic paint which matches your fixture.
Now you have a spacer to mount the fixture on and although it will overhang the top of the mirror slightly, I bet you'll hardly notice it ...

Comment: good suggestion, I was thinking the same thing. Maybe this may work too? ARLON Round Plastic Electrical Box Cover

Comment: I don't think covering the box with flammable wood is code compliant or safe - part of the reason why junction boxes are supposed to be covered is so they contain any sparks or overheated wires that may result from a bad connection. Covering the box with wood doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: So use a more suitable material for the spacer (e.g. aluminum, can be worked with wood tools). But I agree the idea is the easiest way to deal with this.

Comment: Johnny is correct, you cannot use flammable materials for this spacer.  I would use drywall.  However, even this is not proper, as you are not allowed to cover up a box with anything that is part of the house.